# Blue Prism - Collection to Object

Tags: blueprism

I'm looking to feed a collection from my process to my business object.
My object is designed to run multiple statements.  Instead of storing the statement numbers in the object as a data item, I would like the data pulled from my process.  I currently have a collection in my process studio with an Action to pull from and Excel workbook.  Not sure how to feed the collection to my business object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass any data or collection item from process to object, you need to set it up as parameter, at the "start box" of that action.