# how to pass the collections data from process studio to object studio using input and output paramters in blue prism

Tags: blueprism

Creating a demo process for calling BP travels VBO in Blue Prism. Want to capture the data in the create quote tab using capture collection in Process Studio and pass the data to a collection inside an object in Object Studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blue Prism - Collection to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48918125/blue-prism-collection-to-object)

Comment: The BPTravel exercise, formally known as the "Blue Prism Advanced Consolidation Exercise", is just that: **advanced**. This topic is covered extensively in the Blue Prism Foundation Training Guide, which is a required pre-requisite to these exercises. Consider re-visiting the Object Studio chapter of the Foundations training.

Answer (score 2):

First capture the data in the "create quote" tab into a collection item in your process. Then go to the object in Object Studio and inside the Start stage, Add a new input:
[image]

In the object, create a collection item and call it the same as the collection item in the process; then use it to populate the "Store In" field in the Start new input as shown in the picture above - OK.  Then add any other stages you need in your object and remember to publish your object and save.  This is to make the object available to your process in Process Studio.

Then back in your process, use an Action stage to use your object and the page inside the object where you created the (duplicate)collection item.  When you run this stage from your process what will happen is that the data from "quote tab" that you captured inside the collection item in your process, will be passed to the (duplicate) collection item inside your object (as long as they both have the exact same name).

To do the reverse, you will be adding an output to the End stage in your object, and adding an input to the Start stage of your process.

Comment: Thanks, if you are happy with that would you mind accepting as the answer so this can be closed please.

Answer (score 0):

1. First Open VBO- BP travels and open the respective action page
2. Now drag and drop a collection data item and name it as "Input collection" and click on Ok
3. Then open start stage and click on Add and enter the following
   Name as  Input collection
   Description as  Collection that is passed from process studio to object studio
   Type as  collection
   Store In as Input collection i.e., the collection data item name which you created in step 2

After adding the details, click on ok and then save and publish the object.

4. Now open the process and open the respective Action stage i.e., where you are calling the object and have a glance in Inputs tab
5. Now the name added in step 3 i.e., Input Collection will be reflected here.
6. Now drag and drop the collection i.e., Capture Collection which you wished to pass to object studio.

When you run this stage the a copy of capture collection will be passed from process studio to object studio.

Note:
If you want to pass the collection data from object studio to process studio
follow the same process but in object studio you should create in End stage
which will be reflecting in Process Studio -> Action stage -> Outputs tab