# How to get text from a window, and write the data to the collection in Blueprism?

Tags: automation, blueprism, rpa

I'm a beginner on Blue Prism, I have covered some of the basics. One of the exercise requires mo to capture the reference number from a window. I already know how to get it using 'object' window , my problem is that I can't get the output of that object to my 'process' window. I need to update the collection on the 'process' page with the details from the 'object'. Any help is appreciated, or a link to a detailed tutorial.

Comment: Duplicate of [how to pass the collections data from process studio to object studio using input and output paramters in blue prism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153645/how-to-pass-the-collections-data-from-process-studio-to-object-studio-using-inpu)

Comment: This is also covered extensively in the Blue Prism Foundation Training as it is functionality core to the platform. If you haven't completed the training yet I would recommend it as a pre-requisite to any development activity you may undertake.